# Align left tab elements

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to modify this [example](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#vertical-tabs)  for Vertical tabs.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v0p58

I would like to align the tabs on the left side. I tried to add: `alignItems: 'left'`

```
tabs: {
    borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    overflow: 'visible',
    alignItems: 'left'
  },
```

But it's not working. Do you know how I can remove uppercase configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align-items` on a flex ( with default flex-direction:row ) aligns the items on the Y axis, not the X axis.

For the X axis use `justify-content`.

You can style the `MuiTab-wrapper` like so

```
 tabs: {
     "& .MuiTab-wrapper": {
       flexDirection: "row",
       justifyContent: "flex-start"
     },
     textALign: "left",
     borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`
  }
```

Check also [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6hlmk?file=/demo.tsx)

To style the right border ( that's the ' indicator ' ) you can make a class rule and apply that to the indicator

See below

```
 indicator: {
     left: 0,
     // you can add other styles here like changing the backgrounColor
  },
 .... rest of the classes
```

And in jsx add TabIndicatorProps to the  `<Tab` component

```
  <Tabs
    orientation="vertical"
    variant="scrollable"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
    className={classes.tabs}
    TabIndicatorProps={{ className: classes.indicator }}
  >
```

To make the text lowercase just add   `textTransform: 'lowercase'` to the `MuiTab-wrapper` styles

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask one more question: https://ibb.co/C91kDhf How I can move this red line on the left side?

Comment: @PeterPenzov use `borderLeft` instead of `borderRight` ? :)

Comment: Yes, this moves the gray line on the left - not also the red line.

Comment: And one more last question. Do you know how I can make the text lower case? Looks like now automatically uppercase is applied for tabs names?

Comment: @PeterPenzov answered all the questions . Check edited answer

Comment: I implemented the changes but I found one small issue: https://ibb.co/cgzFFK9 when I apply ` textTransform: 'lowercase'` I get all letters to be small. Is it possible to have the first letter of the tab title to be capital or completely disable uppercase conversion somehow?

Comment: @PeterPenzov . yes. use `textTransform: capitalize` :). As a suggestion. You could solve these requests ( from the comments ) with 5 minutes ( MAX ! ) of google search ...